# Auto increamented field in webforms

Tags: 7, webforms

I need to create a auto generated number in web forms. I have used serial module for this but its working on webform in content. Please help me how i can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module and alter the fields value using [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

```
<?php

function pahcom_form_edit_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id =='formid) {
        $new_value = rand(100000,10000000);
        $form['submitted']['vendor_id']['#default_value']=$new_value;
        //$form['submitted']['vendor_id']['<h</h4>default_value']=$new_value;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the sid of the submission? This will already auto increment

Comment: ya i know that but i have to crate another field. can we store sid in different variable on same form

Comment: Yea, you can either create a hidden field on a multi step form have it updated with SID token (provided its after 1st page) or alternatively use the webform API to update the field with the sid programatically